# Create ImageView programmatically without Layout

Tags: java, android, imageview, surfaceview

I'm trying to create an ImageView in code, setting the image resource and then add the ImageView as a child-view to my main view. All examples I found used a layout for that. But inside the constructor of my view I can't figure out how to do that.

Here are the code snippets:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new CanvasView(this));

    }
}
```

The view:

```
public class CanvasView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    public CanvasView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        SurfaceHolder sh = getHolder();
        sh.addCallback(this);

        ImageView iv = new ImageView(context);
        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.wand);

        // how to add iv to myself?
    }
}
```

Comment: Why `ImageView` ? You can directly draw the `Bitmap` using `onDraw` method of the `SurfaceView` right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can not do that this way. you need a container for both: For instance

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new MyContainer(this));

    }
}

public class MyContainer extends LinearLayout {
  public MyContainer(Context context) {
    addView(new CanvasView(context));
    ImageView iv = new ImageView(context);
    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.wand);
    addView(iv);
  }
}
```

remember that if you need to inflate the view directly from a xml file you need, for both `MyContainer` and `CanvasView` the constructor thats takes as parameters `Context` and `AttributeSet`

Comment: In this case the ImageView will be filling my CanvasView?

Comment: no it does not. Do you need to draw a Bitmap inside the SurfaceView?

Comment: Yeah, that was basically what I was trying. But I can derive my View from ImageView instead of SurfaceView too.

Comment: or you can also override SurfaceView.draw and use canvas.drawBitmap

Comment: True, that's what I'm currently trying ;)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on layout that you use, here is some code there all views are created programmatically.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    LinearLayout rootLayout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
    rootLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.sample);

    rootLayout.addView(imageView);

    setContentView(rootLayout);
}
```